# Two different SQL statement generated by same Linq and Lambda expression

Tags: c#, performance, lambda

This is Linq for Left Join -

```
var Records = from cats in Context.Categories
         join prods in Context.Products on cats.Id equals prods.Category_Id into Cps
         from results in Cps.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new { CatName = cats.Name, ProdName = results.Name };
```

This is Lambda Expression for same -

```
var Records = Context.Categories.GroupJoin(Context.Products, c => c.Id, p => p.Category_Id, (c, p) => new { CatName = c.Name, Prods = p });
```

Linq uses SQL-

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1]
FROM  [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Category_Id]
```

And Lambda Uses Following SQL -

```
 SELECT 
 [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
 [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
 [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
 [Project1].[Category_Id] AS [Category_Id], 
 [Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
 [Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
 [Project1].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
 [Project1].[Price] AS [Price]
 FROM ( SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent2].[Category_Id] AS [Category_Id], 
[Extent2].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
[Extent2].[Price] AS [Price], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Category_Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
FROM  [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Category_Id])  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

My Question is why same statement returning different SQL?

Comment: Primarily, I'd guess, because they are not the same statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same query at all - you've got the `GroupJoin` in the lambda expression version, sure - but you haven't got the `SelectMany` that would correspond to:

```
from results in Cps.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

It gets a bit complicated working out the exact query translation due to the transparent identifiers introduced, but I'm sure that's the difference.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, now my new expression would be                              var Records = Context.Categories.GroupJoin(Context.Products, c => c.Id, p => p.Category_Id, (c, p) => new { Cat = c, Prod = p }).SelectMany(c=>c.Prod.DefaultIfEmpty(),(c,p)=>new {c.Cat,p})  ;

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to Jon's response you have:

```
var Records = Context.Categories.GroupJoin(Context.Products, c => c.Id, p => p.Category_Id, (c, p) => new { CatName = c.Name, Prods = p });
```

which has `Prods = p` (pulling the whole product record) where the Linq query has `ProdName = results.Name` (pulling just the name string from the grouped results). That's a fair number of differences.

Try entering your Linq into [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) and seeing what the resultant Lamba looks like in the results pane.